# Error while creating video with images using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using below command for creating video using multiple images

```
String strCommand = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + picturePath + 
" -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + picturePath1 +
" -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + picturePath2 + 
" -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + picturePath3 + 
" -filter_complex [0:v]trim=duration=3,
fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v0];
[1:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v1];
[2:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v2];
[3:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v3];[v0]
[v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -preset ultrafast 
" + videoPath;
```

then i am executing the qwery

```
String[] mycommand = strCommand.split(" ");
execFFmpegBinary(mycommand );
```

But i am facing error while executing , i tried a lot but did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I write a reply cause I cannot comment.
I think you're using http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/ cause I had a similar problem.

---

Check our problem is in your `String strCommand` which arguments aren'tall separated by a white space " ".
You could directly try to create the String[] full command like this

Ex:

```
String [] cmd = {"arg0", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", ... ... ... }
```

Or in your case:

```
String [] cmd = {"-loop", "1", "-t", "3", ... ... ... }
```

**Each arg must be a single element in cmd[].**

I hope that it helps.

---

**Edit**: Take care also about the "ffmpeg" initial tag. It may be implicit and then recognized as arg: try to omit it.